# Why doesn't Ruby on Rails support page-specific javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Typically when I have to solve a problem that RoR doesn't have a direct solution for, it's because I'm not adhering to best practices. I'm new to RoR (and web dev) and I needed a way to include javascript on specific pages. After doing a quick search, I found many different solutions to this, each with its own set of pros/cons, but none of them really address why this isn't a feature in RoR. I understand the benefits of combining/minifying all the files, but as a newcomer, it seems like such an obvious feature that should be inherent to the asset pipeline. Why doesn't Ruby on Rails support page-specific javascript/css? Am I not adhering to certain best practices if I find myself writing page-specific javascript/css?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

It does support it. You just don't require it via sprocket within application.js and an extra file to the assets.precompile config option

```
#layouts/application.html
<head><%= yield(:js)  %></head>

#views/specific/index.html.erb
<% content_for(:js) do %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'specific' %>
<% end %>

#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ['specific.js']

#assets folder
- assets
  - javascripts
    - application.js
    - specific.js
```

You can also put the following regex into assets.precompile in order to have all the javascripts (not beginning with an underscopre) precompiled separately

```
 config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
```

See also [4.1 Precompiling Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks. This was one of the many different solutions I came across during my search, but like all the others, I don't see it in any of the Rails docs, including the Assets guide that you linked to. The 4.1 Assets guide only shows a controller-specific solution... <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %> To be honest, there are a couple other solutions that are a bit cleaner than the one you proposed. Anyhow, thanks again.